# The lookup that you defined is not guaranteed to return single value

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

Error:

> The lookup that you defined is not guaranteed to return single value. If more than value is returned only the firs value will be used

How to return multiple values from a lookup column?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is SharePoint Designer, which you must use a dictionary in that case. Your lookup will return only one item, but if you want you can build a dictionary to house multiple items from a list using a view.

[image]

Check out this link (Source of image): https://plumsail.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-work-with-dictionaries-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-workflow/#QueryListToDictionary